# Powershell script to search for file types from a list of machines, then copy results into directories named after the machine

Tags: powershell

Here's what I have working so far.  It's searching a list of computers placing all the files from all the machines in one folder.

I'm trying to get the files located to be placed in a folder named after the machine that they came from.  Any ideas anyone?

```powershell
Get-Content C:\computers.txt | Foreach-Object {
    $ComputerName = $_    
    Get-Childitem "\\$ComputerName\c$\Documents and Settings\**\desktop","\\$ComputerName\c$\Documents and Settings\**\My Documents" -Include *.xls*, *.doc*, *.txt, *.pdf, *.jpg -Recurse -Force
} | Copy-Item -Destination \\destination\share
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `Copy-Item` inside the loop and add a statement to create the destination folder:

```
$extensions = '*.xls*', '*.doc*', '*.txt', '*.pdf', '*.jpg', '*.pub'

Get-Content C:\computers.txt | % {
  $ComputerName = $_

  $dst = "\\destination\share\$ComputerName"
  $src = "\\$ComputerName\c$\Documents and Settings\**\desktop",
         "\\$ComputerName\c$\Documents and Settings\**\My Documents"

  New-Item -ItemType Directory $dst

  Get-Childitem $src -Include $extensions -Recurse -Force |
    Copy-Item -Destination $dst\
}
```

Comment: This is awesome!  Thanks!  One problem though, PS is telling me "Missing argument in parameter list." on the comma after *.xls*  

Here's the output of the script:   

At line:1 char:21
+ $extensions = *.xls*, *.doc*, *.txt, *.pdf, *.jpg
+                     ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument

Comment: @user3407887: Put the extension patterns in quotes. See updated answer.

Comment: Just noticed that, when I copied and pasted the quotes didn't carry over.  My apologies for overlooking that, got it.  It threw me another error: The term '\\mycomputer\c$\users\myname\desktop\$ComputerName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  Threw some quotes around the $dst variable path and that did the trick. $dst = "\\destination\share\$ComputerName"  Thanks again!

Comment: I have one last request if possible to add to this script.  My goal is to back up specific file types from a list of machines.  These machines have approx 10-20 profiles on them.  Would it be possible to arrange these files in a directory under the computer name directory from the profile they came from?  Such as creating a profile name directory under the created computer name directory then dump the targeted files in their appropriate folder.

Example:
\\server\share\computername1\profile1\document.doc

\\server\share\computername2\Profile2\document.doc

Comment: Possible: yes. But a substantial change to your original question, so it'd warrant a new question.