# Powershell Find PDFs in parent folder and move them to a subfolder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a Powershell script that will search for .pdf files in the parent directory and move them to a subfolder.

For example the .pdf for John Doe is found in: Studies\Doe John\Doe John.pdf.

I would like it to move to: Studies\Doe John\Reports

There are multiple reports to move at one so there would also be Jane Doe in: Studies\Doe Jane

I am at a loss on how to get this to work. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the code you are trying along with any error messages, a description of what the result should be, and how the current result does not meet the requirements. If you need to hire a programmer, try https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples all over this forum regarding how to do this. Just use the search box to fin them.

For example:
"I'm trying to get the files located to be placed in a folder named after the machine that they came from."

[Powershell script to search for file types from a list of machines, then copy results into directories named after the machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336359/powershell-script-to-search-for-file-types-from-a-list-of-machines-then-copy-re)

So, your query could easily be considered a duplicate of the above forum post.

What you are asking for is a common thing.
Just enter you exact post heading into any search engine, and you'll get a lot of hits on the topic. Finding a file is just finding a file, it does not matter what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try This... This worked for me
`Get-Childitem "D:\testfolder1" -Include *.pdf -Recurse -Force| Copy-Item -Destination "D:\testfolder"`